# Search extension for first name = last name (to purge spam submissions)

Tags: extension, custom-search, spam

Some years back there was [a forum discussion about a custom search](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=27351.0) to find contacts where the first name was equal to the last name, which is (or was) common for spam submissions that ended up generating contacts.

A [custom search](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC44/Spam+name+search) was shared but I was curious if anyone had this working on a more recent version of CiviCRM via an extension. (If not, I may play with that).

Comment: Finally got round to trying this.
Works very well indeed. I expected quite a few but not a thousand.
Very strange this because they were all created in batches but no evidence of creating a Drupal User.
I cant figure out what the purpose of the spammer is really.
Thanks for your work creating this extension. Saved me a lot of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CiviCRM 5.69+ [can do this with SearchKit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28112).  *Entity* is **Contact**.  Under *Where*, select `First Name`, `=`, then change `Value` to `Field`.  Then you can select `Last Name`.

Answer (score 3):

Now that I got my computer set up with `buildkit`, I had a chance to [play further with `civix`](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension#CreateaModuleExtension-Addacustomsearch) and built a simple "first name = last name" search extension to test this out and practice the basics of `civix`.

If anyone wants to try it let me know how it goes:

https://github.com/CEDC/org.cedc.namename

Comment: good work on this. i found that setting first != last as a validation on webforms was a great spam reducer where webforms were the entry point.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion where do you set that at?

Comment: webform has a Form Validation tab (from memory) under the Webform tab

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the extension you are looking for is https://civicrm.org/extensions/aug-searches .